# Download Excel related attachments from Outlook inbox and save it in a specific folder based on date range using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

1. Here i want to download all excel related attachments from Outlook application based on date range.
2. All downloaded attachments save it a desktop folder.
3. When i run the below code it's downloading all attachments from outlook and saving in mydocuments folder.

   ```
    Const sPath As String = "C:\Users\Documents\Attachments\"

    Sub Shortage_Attachments3()
    Dim ns As Namespace
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder, SubFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    Dim FileName As String

    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each Item In Inbox.Items
        For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
            FileName = Atmt.FileName
            If Len(dir(sPath & FileName)) > 0 Then FileName = sPath & Format(Item(I).ReceivedTime, "DDMMYYYY") & "_" & Format(Now, "DDMMYYHHMMSS") & FileName
                Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
        Next Atmt
      Next Item

    MsgBox "Download Complete.", vbInformation, "SUCCESS"

    End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code to get the extension of the file in the attachment and then check if it is an xl file. Can you please try and run the code and let me know if you hav eany query.
Thanks.

```
Const sPath As String = "C:\Users\Documents\Attachments\"

 Sub Shortage_Attachments3()
 Dim ns As namespace
 Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder, SubFolder As MAPIFolder
 Dim Item As Object
 Dim Atmt As Attachment
 Dim FileName As String
 Dim blnxlFile As Boolean
 Dim intPos As Integer
 Dim strExtn As String

 Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

 On Error Resume Next

 For Each Item In Inbox.Items
     For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
         blnxlFile = False
         FileName = Atmt.FileName
         intPos = InStr(1, FileName, ".", vbTextCompare)
         If intPos > 0 Then
            strExtn = Mid(FileName, intPos + 1, Len(FileName) - intPos)
            If Left(strExtn, 2) = "xl" Then
                blnxlFile = True
            End If
         End If
         If Len(Dir(sPath & FileName)) > 0 And blnxlFile = True Then
            FileName = sPath & Format(Item(i).ReceivedTime, "DDMMYYYY") & "_" & Format(Now, "DDMMYYHHMMSS") & FileName
            Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
         End If
     Next Atmt
   Next Item

 MsgBox "Download Complete.", vbInformation, "SUCCESS"

 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for you help... I have ran the above code which you have shared, i can't see the downloaded excel files in specified folder. Could you please check it once again and I want to download all excel related files(xlsx, xls, .csv, xlsm) based on particular days if you could add the particular dates (From date and To date based on excel sheet range)  that would be very helpful. Thank you in advance, Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try and run the below revised code.

I have made the following changes to the code:

1.)You can now add the from date and To date ranges in the code itself. All the emails with received date falling within the given range will qualify for attachment to be saved.

2.) All xl files and CSV files now will be qualified to be saved.

```
Const sPath As String = "C:\Users\Documents\Attachments\"

Sub saveAttachments()
 Dim ns As namespace
 Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder, SubFolder As MAPIFolder
 Dim Item As Object
 Dim Atmt As Attachment
 Dim FileName As String
 Dim FileFullName As String
 Dim blnxlFile As Boolean
 Dim intPos As Integer
 Dim strExtn As String
 Dim FromDate As Date
 Dim ToDate As Date, DtEmailDate As Date
 Dim blnDate As Boolean

 Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
 FromDate = #5/2/2020#   'Change the from Date here
 ToDate = #5/31/2020#    ' Change the To date here
    
 On Error Resume Next

 For Each Item In Inbox.Items
     For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
         blnxlFile = False
         blnDate = False
         FileName = Atmt.FileName
         intPos = InStr(1, FileName, ".", vbTextCompare)
         If intPos > 0 Then
            strExtn = Mid(FileName, intPos + 1, Len(FileName) - intPos)
            If Left(strExtn, 2) = "xl" Or Left(strExtn, 2) = "csv" Then
                blnxlFile = True
                DtEmailDate = DateValue((Format(Item.ReceivedTime, "DD/MM/YYYY")))
            End If
         End If
         
         If DtEmailDate >= FromDate And DtEmailDate <= ToDate Then
            blnDate = True
         End If
         
         If blnxlFile = True And blnDate = True Then
            FileFullName = sPath & Format(Item.ReceivedTime, "DDMMYYYY") & "_" & Format(Now, "DDMMYYHHMMSS") & FileName
            Atmt.SaveAsFile FileFullName ' sPath & FileName
         End If
     Next Atmt
   Next Item

 MsgBox "Download Complete.", vbInformation, "SUCCESS"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I ran the above code now i am able to downloading attachments but few attachments only downloading, i can't downloading all attachments. i have given FromDate = #2/27/2021# and ToDate = #3/1/2021#. but DtEmailDate is showing other then these dates it's showing like #11/25/2020. Could you pls help me on this. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have made certain modifications in the loop and have tested the code as well. It will take only those emails which will match with the date criteria and will then check if the attachments are matching for xl and csv file extension. Hope the code should work now in the manner it should be. Thanks!!

```
Const sPath As String = "C:\Users\Documents\Attachments\"

Sub saveAttachments()
 Dim ns As namespace
 Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder, SubFolder As MAPIFolder
 Dim Item As Object
 Dim Atmt As Attachment
 Dim FileName As String
 Dim FileFullName As String
 Dim blnxlFile As Boolean
 Dim intPos As Integer
 Dim strExtn As String
 Dim FromDate As Date
 Dim ToDate As Date, DtEmailDate As Date
 Dim blnDate As Boolean

 Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
 FromDate = #5/2/2020#   'Change the from Date here
 ToDate = #5/31/2020#    ' Change the To date here
    
 On Error Resume Next

 For Each Item In Inbox.Items
     blnDate = False
     DtEmailDate = DateValue((Format(Item.ReceivedTime, "DD/MM/YYYY")))
     If DtEmailDate >= FromDate And DtEmailDate <= ToDate Then
        blnDate = True
     End If
     
     If blnDate = True Then
        For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
            blnxlFile = False
            strExtn = ""
            FileName = Atmt.FileName
            intPos = InStr(1, FileName, ".", vbTextCompare)
            If intPos > 0 Then
               strExtn = Mid(FileName, intPos + 1, Len(FileName) - intPos)
               If (Left(strExtn, 2) = "xl") Or (Left(strExtn, 3) = "csv") Then
                   blnxlFile = True
               End If
            End If
            If blnxlFile = True Then
               FileFullName = sPath & Format(Item.ReceivedTime, "DDMMYYYY") & "_" & Format(Now, "DDMMYYHHMMSS") & FileName
               Atmt.SaveAsFile FileFullName ' sPath & FileName
            End If
        Next Atmt
     End If
   Next Item

 MsgBox "Download Complete.", vbInformation, "SUCCESS"

End Sub
```